# 2D statics problem with 5 unknowns?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, equilibrium, statics

In this problem there are 2 hinges (each one with 2 reaction) one at point C [$C_x$,$C_y$] and the other at point G [$G_x$,$G_y$] , Also there is a cable that Dc that has tension $T_{DC}$.

Then how could I possibly solve this with only 3 equations $$\sum{Fx}=0$$
$$\sum{Fy}=0$$
$$\sum{M} =0$$
There must be at least 2 of these rqual to zero , right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also have two equations for equilibrium of the cable.